# можно ли пересоздавать Audio в js?

Tags: javascript, html5, web-audio

Просто у меня такой код:

```
    player.pause();
    player = new Audio('sheeran.mp3');
    player.play();
```

И я боюсь, что объект то может пересоздаваться, но сам физический поток, или честно говоря не представляю что может остаться? То есть как при чтении файла, не закрыть предыдущий, но открыть новый. Может ли быть такое или всё в порядке?

Comment: Я ничего не понял...

Comment: Речь немного безсвязная, но кажется я понял ваш вопрос. Должно быть всё впорядке, но почему просто не создать новый объект?

Comment: но я же это и делаю, конструктором

Comment: я перечитал, что написал, извините)) Просто торопился))

Comment: но я вас понял, спасибо)) теперь спокоен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Так Вы по-новой переобъявляете элемент, поэтому не сможете продолжать дальше слушать то, что до этого было нажато на паузу. Бывает, что в плейлисте для каждой песни используют отдельный элемент аудио, (вернее, это очень часто происходит) тогда любой трек можно остановить в любом месте, и потом слушать дальше.